# How to efficiently make Web Service calls from Hadoop map reduce job MRv1/MRv2

Tags: web-services, hadoop, architecture, hadoop2, hadoop-streaming

The map/reduce job wants to make an inline call to a web service as part of the pipeline. What would be an efficient architecture/stack to create such scalable web-service.

If such web service is bound to run into bottlenecks in shared resources.What are the other options?

For one, we are considering using Hadoop Streaming to call directly the individual components of core logic of the web service from map/reduce job